# Why the overloaded operator doesn't work?

Tags: c++, oop

I am working on a C++ project that works with polynomials stored in a LinkedList. I want to overload important operators such as +, -, *, /.
I had some issues with destructor when the function returns the result.

```
 Polynomial& Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial &p){
    Polynomial  sum = *this;

    if (p.list.isEmpty())
        return *this;

    ListElement *temp = p.list.first;

    while (temp){
        sum.list.addSorted(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This function works very good, but `return sum;` calls the destructor and I lose the data. The destructor from Polynomial class calls `list.purge();` which frees the dynamic memory in linked list. All the classes and its methods are good.

In main I have:

```
Polynomial p1,p2,sum;
p1.input();              //here I input data for first pol
p2.input();

sum=p1+p2;               //I overloaded operator=, it works fine
```

What I must do "to stop" the destructor? I want to output on screen Polynomial `sum`. Thank you!

Comment: Don't return a local variable by reference.

Comment: `Polynomial& Polynomial::...` -> `Polynomial Polynomial::...`

Comment: It's also probably not a good idea for `operator+` to mangle the original value it's operating on. To avoid doing that, declare this method as `const`.

Comment: jaggedSpire, I tried this. `sum` is NULL in main. Thus, the destructor was called.

Comment: Ursu, are you familiar with the Rule of Three? If not, give [What is the Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) a read.

Comment: FYI, see "Canonical implementations" in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to overload operator `+` this way:

```
Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& p1, const Polynomial &p2){
    if (p1.list.isEmpty())
        return p2;
    else if (p2.list.isEmpty())
        return p1;

    Polynomial sum = p1;
    ListElement *temp = p2.list.first;
    while (temp){
        sum.list.addSorted(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**1.** Let it have two parameters, and make it `friend` to class `Polynomial`

**2.** Return `object` instead of `reference`

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD NOT return a reference to a local variable!

```
Polynomial  sum = *this;

...

return sum;
```

Remove the `&` from the return type. `sum` lives on the stack (aka in automatic storage). When its containing scope exits, it is destroyed-- the destructor for that instance is called. You should not return a reference to it; it's like returning a reference to a ghost.

If you return by value, a copy of sum will be returned and you will be OK.

Comment: Yes, but if OP hasn't observed the Rule of Three they are still up a creek. You don't want to know where the paddle is.

Comment: You're correct, he should definitely learn it and abide by it.

Comment: You're correct, he should definitely learn it and abide by it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return a reference to the local variable. Objects that are created within a function scope, live and die within that scope.

You can however, create variables which are references to objects, and the lifetime of that variable is now the same as the life time of the object it references.

Like this:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial &p){
    Polynomial &sum = *this;

    if (p.list.isEmpty())
        return sum;

    ListElement *temp = p.list.first;

    while (temp){
        sum.list.addSorted(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `sum` is not NULL now and it is great, but I lose p1's data. I mean that :
_p1=5X^2     p2=X^2_
after operator function
_sum=6X^2_     **p1=6X^2** instead of 5X^2          p2=X^2

How to deal with this?